# Javascript doing what is expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically adding `<script>` tags with javascript & jQuery into my html file whenever a button is pushed. Everything gets added in correctly but only one of the two `.click` jQuery action functions is working. I can't seem to figure out why. No errors in console. I made sure i used `\'` and `\"` in the correct places.

```
$('#classBox').append('<tr id=\"' + tempCHAR + tempNUM + '\">' 
                + '<td>' 
                    + '<i id=\"' + tempCHAR + tempNUM + '\" class=\"icon-remove-sign\">'
                    + '</i> '
                    + '<a id=\"' + tempCHAR + tempNUM + '\"" href=\"https://cms.psu.edu/section/default.asp?id=' + urlHOLDER + '\" target="framehidden">' 
                        + tempYEAR + ': ' + tempCHAR + tempNUM + ', Section ' + tempSEC 
                    + '</a>'
                + '</td>'
            + '</tr>'
            + '<script>'
                + '$(\'#' + tempCHAR + tempNUM + '\').click(function() {'
                    + '$(\'tr\').remove(\'tr#' + tempCHAR + tempNUM + '\');'
                + '});'
                + '$(\'a#\'' + tempCHAR + tempNUM + ').click(function() {'
                    + '$(\'#framehidden\').attr(\'src\', $(\'a\', this).attr(\'href\')));'
                + '});'
            + '</script>');
```

The indents are just for me to more easily read what I'm doing. That wouldn't be the problem would it?

If thats too impossible to read then here it is in normal view.

```
$('a#'IST130).click(function() {
    $('#framehidden').attr('src', $('a', this).attr('href')));
});  
$('#IST130').click(function() {
    $('tr').remove('tr#IST130');
});
```

I have like 30 other `.click` functions that all work perfectly but I just cannot figure out what is going wrong here. Any hints?

Comment: ID's must be unique. additionally, you have a typo here: `$('a#'IST130)`

Comment: Consider revising your solution to only append HTML content and dynamically apply triggers after it is appended, instead of appending script tags.

Comment: There's no need to append the `script` the way you are. Use event delegation in your main script block: `$(document).on('click',selector,function() {...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.append()` is instant (ie. synchronous), there is absolutely no need to put that stuff in a `<script>` tag. Instead, try this:

```
$('#classBox').append('<tr id=\"' + tempCHAR + tempNUM + '\">' 
            + '<td>' 
                + '<i id=\"' + tempCHAR + tempNUM + '\" class=\"icon-remove-sign\">'
                + '</i> '
                + '<a id=\"' + tempCHAR + tempNUM + '\"" href=\"https://cms.psu.edu/section/default.asp?id=' + urlHOLDER + '\" target="framehidden">' 
                    + tempYEAR + ': ' + tempCHAR + tempNUM + ', Section ' + tempSEC 
                + '</a>'
            + '</td>'
        + '</tr>');
$('#' + tempCHAR + tempNUM).click(function() {
    $('tr').remove('tr#' + tempCHAR + tempNUM);
});
$('a#' + tempCHAR + tempNUM).click(function() {
    $('#framehidden').attr('src', $('a', this).attr('href')));
});
```

That being said, your code is HORRIBLY invalid. IDs MUST be unique. I'll leave you to fix that in whatever way works best for you, but yeah.

Comment: this worked perfectly. i fixed a couple of errors and then made the ID's unique and now it works like a breeze. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your error (or at least one of them) is on this line:

```
+ '$(\'a#\'' + tempCHAR + tempNUM + ').click(function() {'
```

Just have an extra single quote there that needs to be moved to the end of the `$()` block:

```
+ '$(\'a#' + tempCHAR + tempNUM + '\').click(function() {'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example at the end you have `$('a#'IST130)`. Pretty sure that should read `$('a#IST130`)`

To correct it, change the generation for that ID to:

```
'$(\'a#' + tempCHAR + tempNUM + '\')...
```

Additionally, since you are dynamically adding the elements, their click events may not bind properly, depending on exactly when your code is executing.

You can use [jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to set a bind for the events on a permanent element. In this case `#classBox` looks like a good bet. It might look something like this (where this would be inside a normal script block and outside of your dynamic stuff:

```
$('#classBox').on('click','a',function () {
    $('#framehidden').attr('src', $('a', this).attr('href')));
});

$('#classBox').on('click',function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Note: Completely untested - intended as a guide!

Comment: yeah that was something i fixed before. I have two of these sections in my javascript fix but i was only working on one. Must have copied the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

After you fix the syntax errors, also be sure the click events aren't being attached before the `append()` code has run.

I can't tell which order the code runs in the actual page - if you're appending the elements before the click events are being attached, the elements may not exist yet. You can use jQuery's `delegate` method to ensure the events are called for all elements, no matter when they're appended to the DOM.

For example:

`$('body').delegate('.anchorClassName', 'click', function(e){});`